# Android Install Cer file programmatically

Tags: android, certificate

I have a android app, I am using `webView` to view html pages, all works fine but I have a link which is `SSL` and the certificate is self signed. Without installing certificate `webview` does not show anything, but when I manually installed Certificate Under *Setting > Security > Install* from Phone Storage, `webview` shows website, also I can see the Certificate installed in Trusted Credentials under users tab.

Now my requirement is that the *APK should automatically install the certificat*e.

I have tried multiple code found on Internet one of them is below.

```
public static void setCustomCertificateAuthority(InputStream inputStream) {

    try {
        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            Log.e("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN(),"ssss");
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore and system CA
        UnifiedTrustManager trustManager = new UnifiedTrustManager(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);

        // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call the above method in `onCreate` event of **Main.java** using

```
 try {
            InputStream caInput=getAssets().open("mycert.cer");
            setCustomCertificateAuthority(caInput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The Code works fine no exception but when I go in *Setting > Security > Trusted Credentials > User Tab*, I cannot find the Certificate. also `webview` doesn't show anything.

Comment: did you solve it?