# how to programmatically install an SSL CA certificate on a device that runs android?

Tags: android, ssl, embedded

I am working with some devices that happen to use Android as the OS. One runs Android L, the other, N. We run a custom NDK app as the launcher. The devices are manufactured for us, and we sell them. The devices drive displays in meeting rooms and allow users to wirelessly share their content. They can also provide digital signage.

I need for administrators to be able to remotely upload an in-house CA certificate that the device will then honor. The problem is that I've been googling and still don't understand what to do with the CA certificate once I get it on device. The install technique cannot require user interaction with the device.

These are not certificates that can be pre-installed. They must be installable dynamically by owners of the devices who have their own in-house certificate authority.

Our app is predominantly C++ NDK. It doesn't run as a system app, but it can run shell commands as root. Of course, we can call Java code.

So, what do I do to make the device use an uploaded CA certificate?

Comment: You should probably build this into the custom AOSP system image from the start.  Otherwise you're basically asking how to use the root shell to hack your own devices, which is a bit of a kludge.  The design intent is that certificates arrive either as a result of being built in by the system image maker, perhaps as part of a mobile device management app (you'd need to research that), or by explicit user interaction to consent.  Anything that looks like a "stealth" installation from an ordinary app is going to be guarded against as that is basically an unauthorized attack on a user's device.

Comment: More importantly, you are perhaps asking the wrong question - rather than add the certificate to the *device* you can merely package it in the specific custom app which needs to use it.  Both Google and also even Apple permit apps to bring along a certificate to use when validating their own communication with their own servers, it's putting the certificate on the device globally for other unconsenting apps to use which is limited.

Comment: If it is your own sites you are trying to secure, you don't need this, you can either package your own cert in the apps that need it or get real ones from an already recognized CA.  You only need a global custom cert to man-in-the-middle other non-consenting sites, or to do something dubious that a CA would not permit, like have a cert against an IP address which your users could access from the default browser.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough about the devices and how they are used, so the previous comments are off-point. I have edited the original posting to clarify.

Comment: Your update only invalidates the preinstallatiin idea, you can still have your apps that need to verify remote hosts against the cert put a cert literally anywhere they like after obtaining it by any means you trust.  You do not have to "install" it but merely use it in your own app's SSL or whatever code.

Comment: But what I don't understand is once I have a customer-provided CA certificate, is how do I use it? That part of my question is still outstanding. If that part of my question is a duplicate, I'd love to be pointed to an existing answer.

Comment: You use it by providing it to the APIs of whatever *unspecified* ssl implementation your code is using.

Comment: I now understand your answer. We have 3 ways we can make client requests, in C++ code using cURL, in Rust code that probably goes thru OpenSSL, and thru webviews in Android Java. The cURL and Rust  APIs I can figure out. What I'm least familiar with and need help on is the Android Java side of things.

Comment: I learned a bunch of stuff based on my study of libcurl. What I now plan to do is have users remotely upload a CA certificate bundle. Then, at app startup I will concatenate our standard bundle (read-only) with the customer-provided bundle to a third bundle file. Libcurl and Rust will be pointed to use the third bundle file. What I don't know yet, and still need help with, is how to tell Android Java webviews to use the third bundle. I will update the OP to reflect this.

Comment: I found this: I think the code should come handy for "installing" the certificate into your app. I think you should be able to export (DER format!) the .cer file and place it into a res/raw folder in your app. Then get an input stream for the raw file and use the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244837/android-install-cer-file-programmatically

Exporting can be done via Browser (like Chrome). Or have a look at this tutorial describing how to set up a certificate: 

https://gpotter2.github.io/tutos/en/sslsockets

Did not test it but will do.